# Understanding left outer join using AND on the right elements, still resulting in duplicate entries (with sql fiddle)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sqlfiddle

**My question is: what is the problem in my thinking?**

Why is the left join not working as I thought?

[A working answer was given (without explanation), here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83667/simple-left-outer-join-leaving-me-with-inner-join)

More info way down.

[I have this sql fiddle displaying the problem I am facing when using left outer join](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e766b/7/0)

Structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mychanges` (
  `object_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `version_stamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `object_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`object_id` ,`version_stamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1266, "2014-09-24 09:55:40", "bbbb", 2 );
    INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1236, "2014-09-24 09:55:40", "aaa", 2 );
    INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1226, "2014-09-24 09:55:40", "zzz", 5 );
    INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1216, "2014-09-24 09:55:40", "xxxx", 8 );

    INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1256, "2014-09-24 09:51:40", "name1", 10 );
    INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1256, "2014-09-24 09:52:40", "name2", 10 );
    INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1256, "2014-09-24 09:53:40", "name3", 10 );
    INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1256, "2014-09-24 09:54:40", "name4", null );
    INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1256, "2014-09-24 09:56:40", "name5", null );
```

SELECT

```
SELECT  mychanges.object_id AS objectid1, mychanges.object_name AS objectname1, mychanges.version_stamp AS version_stamp1, change2.project as project2, change2.version_stamp as version_stamp2, change2.object_name as objectname2 FROM mychanges
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from mychanges AS x WHERE x.project IS NULL) AS change2
ON change2.object_id = mychanges.object_id 
WHERE  mychanges.project = 10
```

What I want to get:

The values inserted by

```
INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1256, "2014-09-24 09:51:40", "name1", 10 );
INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1256, "2014-09-24 09:52:40", "name2", 10 );
INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1256, "2014-09-24 09:53:40", "name3", 10 );
INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1256, "2014-09-24 09:54:40", "name4", null );
INSERT INTO mychanges VALUES (1256, "2014-09-24 09:56:40", "name5", null );
```

So in written language: all records that have as project a 10 and all records that have the same object id with a record that has the project id of 10.

Why?

This is a changeset table. A user is changing an object name and hits enter. This generates entries in form of a change. These changes, can, sadly, have a project id of null. The object id is unique though.

**What am I thinking?**

I thought: right we have all entries with project_id NULL. Left we have all records with project_id with 10. If we join them using `object_id`, we get both, without duplicates. But instead we get duplicates of name4 and name5 and not name1, name2, and name3.

Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought: right we have all entries with project_id NULL. Left we
>   have all records with project_id with 10. If we join them, we get
>   both, without duplicates

**No**. You can't join that because the values `NULL` is not comparable with any other value, not even with `NULL`. If you have null, you need to handle it explicitly by using `ifNULL()` function.

**EDIT**

On second look, I realize that you are trying to join with the `object_id` which is of course not null. So let us see what is happening in your query. If I may break your query in 2 parts, the first part is:

```
SELECT  
mychanges.object_id AS objectid1, 
mychanges.object_name AS objectname1, 
mychanges.version_stamp AS version_stamp1
FROM mychanges
WHERE  mychanges.project = 10
```

This produces 3 records with `object_id` = 1256

And the 2nd part is,

```
SELECT * from mychanges AS x WHERE x.project IS NULL
```

This produces 2 records with `object_id` = 1256.

When you join these 2 parts using condition `change2.object_id = mychanges.object_id` it produces 3 X 2 = 6 records in the result. The duplicate originates as for each record in left side, there are 2 records in the right side.

This is exactly what the SQL is supposed to behave.

Comment: I think you can compare it with `is NULL`

Comment: you are aware we don't join on project ID but on object_id, which is not null? i'll fix my text

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx the WHERE clausel is executed after the join. Am I confusing something again?

Comment: Well my question now is, after doing a join: is it possible to access the joined result? obviously in this example `mychanges.project = 10` still refers to the actual table, not the result of the join.

Comment: When the `WHERE` clause is evaluated during the execution has no impact on the final result as the final result will be such that it will always comply the `WHERE` clause condition (predicate).

Comment: `mychanges.project = 10` refers to an intermediate result set. It's neither the actual table not the joined set. Two such intermediate states are getting joined together to form your result